# Lightning:input and Lightning:inputField are different alignment

Tags: lightninginput, lightning-inputfield

I want to use both lightning:input and lightning:inputField in the same component but I cannot format these 2 input types into the same alignment even thought I'm using the same `<div>` tag. For example:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
    <lightning:inputField
      aura:id="inputField"
      fieldName="Use_For__c"
      required="true"
      variant="label-stacked"
      onchange="{!c.onUseForChange}"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
    <lightning:input
      required="true"
      label="Effective Date Start"
      name="effectiveStartDate"
      aura:id="required_field"
      type="date"
      value="{! v.factor.Effective_Date_Start__c }"
      onchange="{! c.onEffectiveDateChange }"
      dateStyle="short"
      messageWhenBadInput="Your entry does not match the allowed format mm/dd/yyyy."
    />
  </div>
[...]
</div>
```

The display screen:

[image]

How can I format these 2 types in the same alignment? Please help, thanks.